# How can i determine if a user is in first table or in second table

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

Hy!
I have 2 tables in my database. The one is `Teachers` and other is `Students`. if a user tries to log in then, How can i determine weather this user is in Teachers table or in Students table

i tried this but it is't working.!

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Teachers` , `Students` 
WHERE Students.username='user's name' 
AND Teachers.username='user's name'
```

Comment: Perhaps you should have only one table of people and then have an attribute that describes whether they are student or teacher.

Comment: Hopefully a teacher cannot be a student and vice versa.

Comment: Your data would appear to need normalising - do you realise with your current query you require them to be *both*? One table is the way to go here. Also refer to [bad habbits to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: mr. salmon it is true but both are users of same site

Comment: Simply i have 2 table of users now i have to determine if user is in first table or in second table. if it is in first table show me full details (According to that table) and same as second table

Comment: If you need the same columns from both tables then you could *union* them - but that would indicate even more they should be in one *Users* table with a *type* = *student* or *teacher*

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT type FROM
(SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT username, 'student' as type FROM Students) t1
    UNION (SELECT username, 'teacher' as type FROM Teachers)
) as subquery WHERE username = 'Student name'
```

Comment: Sir i have 2 tables. The one is Teachers,other is Students.Both have username,password ...otherDetails 
now i want to find if a user is in teacher's table or student's table. 
if it is teachers table show it's full data & same as student.

Comment: I just edited the answer :)

Comment: Mr.Valkoff it worked for me but
can't i do something further like this `select * from type( because the type contains the name of table) where username='username' ???

Comment: Well what you want to achieve already is a bit "borderline", you can try with different approaches, but for what you asked, the answer fits.